# Testing exceptions in Scala

Tags: scala, testing

I want to test (in Intellij Idea testing framework) the following code:

```
def eval(t: Term): Term = t match {
    case t if isVal(t) => t
    case If(t1,t2,t3) if True == eval(t1) => eval(t2)
    case If(t1,t2,t3) if False == eval(t1) => eval(t3)
    case Succ(t) if isNum(eval(t)) => Succ(eval(t))
    case Pred(t) => eval(t) match {
      case Zero => Zero
      case Succ(v) if isNum(v) => v
      case _ => throw TermIsStuck(Pred(eval(t)))
    }
    case IsZero(t) => eval(t) match {
      case Zero => True
      case Succ(v) if isNum(v) =>False
      case _ => throw TermIsStuck(IsZero(eval(t)))
    }
    case _ => throw TermIsStuck(t)
  }
```

For a reference you can see [this repository](https://github.com/wonook/2015_Fall_FoundationsOfSoftware/tree/master/1-arithmetic/src/main/scala/fos). So I wrote the following test:

```
 test("testEval") {

    Arithmetic.term(new Arithmetic.lexical.Scanner("if iszero pred pred 2 then if iszero 0 then true else false else false")) match {
      case Arithmetic.Success(res,next) => assert(eval(res) == True)
      case Arithmetic.Failure(msg,next) => assert(false)
    }

    Arithmetic.term(new Arithmetic.lexical.Scanner("pred succ succ succ false")) match {
      case Arithmetic.Success(res,next) => assert(Arithmetic.eval(res) == TermIsStuck(Succ(False)))
      case Arithmetic.Failure(msg,next) => assert(false)
    }

  }
```

Getting the error:

> Succ(False)
>
> fos.Arithmetic$TermIsStuck: Succ(False) ...

How can I test this catching the error? Indeed this test should be passed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in Scala you are not supposed to throw exception around, but in scalatest you can do something like this:

```
a[yourException.type] should be thrownBy yourFunction()
```

You can do a better version of that,

```
case class Error(exception: Exception){

throw exception

???

}
```

Or something like

```
case object Error
```

And then you check it like:

```
Error shouldBe yourFunction()
```

Comment: @Thilo `test(name) { body }`? Looks like Scalatest with `FunSuite` to me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not using any widespread testing framework for scala (such as [scalatest](http://www.scalatest.org/) or [specs2](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/)) - an obvious recommendation would be to use some.

However, if you'd like to stick with "no-framework" approach, one option would be to use good old `try .. catch`:

```
val term = Arithmetic.term(
  new Arithmetic.lexical.Scanner("pred succ succ succ false")
)
try {
  val evaluated = term match {
      case Arithmetic.Success(res,next) => Arithmetic.eval(res)
      case Arithmetic.Failure(msg,next) => assert(false)
  }
} catch {
  case TermIsStuck(Succ(False)) => // do nothing, or explicitly mark test as successful
  case _ => assert(false) // any other exception should fail the test
}
```

However, I think the implementation is partially broken - it never returns `Arithmetic.Failure`, but throws exception.  I think the intent of `Arithmetic.Failure` was exactly to capture such cases. If that's the case, then better implementation would be to replace `throw TermIsStuck` with `Arithmetic.Failure(TermIsStuck(...))`.

Comment: I'm actually following this guide: https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/intellij-track/testing-scala-in-intellij-with-scalatest.html so I assume I am using scalatest